# Migrating Sleuth to Observation API by Micrometar Spring Boot 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer-tracing

We have Sleuth enabled on all endpoints Spring 2.7.x ( that comes out of the box). Just plain and simple traceId/spanId tracking. Now as in Spring Sleuth is no more available in Spring Boot 3.0.0. Is there a way to enable this new Observation Api on all endpoints.

**Before had this:**

```
/*
 List all beers in database
 */
public Mono<ServerResponse> listBeer() {
    return beerService.listBeers(null,  null, PageRequest.ofSize(50), true)
            .flatMap(beerDto -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(beerDto))
            .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());


}
```

**Now with new Api in every endpoint need to do this:**

```
/*
 List all beers in database
 */
public Mono<ServerResponse> listBeer() {
    Observation observation = Observation.start("listBeer-sample", observationRegistry);
    return Mono.just(observation).flatMap(span -> {

                observation.scoped(() -> log.info("I can fetch trace id <TRACE:{}> ",
                        this.tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId())
                );
                return beerService.listBeers(null, null, PageRequest.ofSize(50), true)
                        .flatMap(beerDto -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(beerDto))
                        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
            }).doFinally(signalType -> observation.stop())
            .contextWrite(context -> context.put(ObservationThreadLocalAccessor.KEY, observation));

}
```

}

Is there a way to enable traceId/spanId out of the box on all endpoints without all of this clutter?

Comment: You should be able to make this an `ExchangeFunction` and use that as a filter when creating the `WebClient`. That way it will apply to all the requests done with the `WebClient`. You can take a look on how Zipkin did it and then take that approach again. Should be a matter of configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum can some example of this be found?

Comment: On hindsight I believe that should work out of the box if the right dependencies are on the classpath. That is what the [`WebFluxObservationAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/web/reactive/WebFluxObservationAutoConfiguration.java) should setup. Using `tap` should be all you need (if I read correctly). See also https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/observability-reactive-spring-boot-3/

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no other way but to be a little bit more verbose and use the tap or handle operator that will automatically put observations in scope. We will be working on better, automated solutions in the future

Comment: G. Is there some examples of tap or handle operator to be found? We are looking most generic/simple solution where traceId will be propagated through our services and callbacks.

Comment: Check this out https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#instrumentation_of_reactive_libraries

Comment: @Levijatanu have a look at this article: https://openvalue.blog/posts/2022/12/16/tracing-in-spring-boot-2-and-3/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think you want to integrate micrometar without changing the original code

Fortunately it can be implemented through `@Observed` + aop

You can refer to the official documentation
Refer to Section 4.6 [observation](https://micrometer.io/docs/observation)

add config code

```
  @Bean
  public ObservedAspect observedAspect(ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
      return new ObservedAspect(observationRegistry, this::skipControllers);
  }
 
  private boolean skipControllers(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
      Class<?> targetClass = pjp.getTarget().getClass();
      return targetClass.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class) || targetClass.isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class);
  }
```

Comment: Does this mean that every endpoint on the controller needs to be annotated with @Observed?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to use this approach, the spring mvc Interceptor will probably do the trick

Comment: Added <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId> and annotated service method with @Observed but this is not working. Trace ide is not added to log output

Comment: see ` io.micrometer.observation.aop.ObservedAspect` source